# How to recover EOS installation on MacBook Pro when no system is longer recognized including USB/Optical boots

Tags: refind

I found myself in that situation where my laptop with originally 4 different boots was taken out of service by an attempt to use BootCamp, after the attempt, a BootCamp partition was successfully created, but the install failed. Trying to recover and unify the partitions again under MacOS recovery, the machine closed off completely stating no available device could be booted from. Even in any MacOS recover modes, USB sticks install wouldn't work except MacOS internet recovery. And my legacy 6,1 MacBook Pro could not even boot from rescue CD/DVD's/USB's since the other machine we had had a Mojave issue not having an access to the optical drive... Nightmarish situation: no solution seemed left. But there is!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that came to my mind, is that I had a sufficiently large USB stick (the only thing I could do is installing MacOS somewhere). Spoof it as a system-install accepted macOS install drive:

formatting it through MacOS emergency mode, in MacOS Extended, selecting GUID-partition table in Disk Utility (I did it on another machine for the safety sake)

then start internet recovery install (I decided to go for OSX Lion, to have the smallest install possible, which was what the default proposition to install made by the recovery mode), and have Lion installed through download on the USB Thumb drive.

It took approx. 2 hours, but it worked: as soon as I could restart in the newly installed Lion, I could install Firefox and download refind zip binary, extract it onto my Lion's desktop,

restart again in safe mode (option+R) and follow the [procedure](https://github.com/aroman/elementary-on-a-mac) to install refind from the terminal there, as the refind install is recognized again, by the terminal where I placed it, on my MacOS Lion desktop!

After restarting (and refind confirming the install is successful), I had access again to my ElementaryOS multi-boot, seamlessly (only the order was changed, so I had to test which one was my latest Juno install).

Walk in the park!